# Transmitting and receiving UDP frames between 2 ethernet ports in same system

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, ethernet

I Have two ethernet ports in my system, 
and I have configured their IP address as- `10.169.20.15` and `10.169.20.30` respectively. I am trying to transmit UDP frames from one application through port with IP address `10.169.20.30`. With another application I am trying to receive the frame through the other ethernet port with IP `10.169.20.15`.

While transmitting I am able to set my source IP address( So that the particular ethernet port with that IP is used for transmitting) and my destination IP address.

But for recieving I dont know how to set the port with IP `10.169.20.15` as the recieve port.

Tx code

```
class Program
{
    static IPEndPoint Mypoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.169.20.30"), 8050);// Source IP 
    static IPEndPoint UrPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.169.20.15"), 8051);// Destination IP
    static UdpClient TxClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        byte [] data= new byte[1472];
        TxClient = new UdpClient(Mypoint);
        while (i < 500)
        {
            data[i]++;
            try
            {
                TxClient.Send(data, data.Length, UrPoint);
            }
            catch { }
            Console.WriteLine("Sent frame " + i + " times\n");
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Rx code

```
class Program
{
   static IPEndPoint RxEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8051); // IP from where I can receive the frame

    static UdpState state1 = new UdpState();
    static UdpClient Rx;
    static int i = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rx = new UdpClient(RxEndpoint);
        state1.Rxclient = Rx;
        state1.Endpoint = RxEndpoint;
        Rx.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback1), state1);
        while (true)
        { }
    }
    public static void RecieveCallback1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        UdpClient Rx1 = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).Rxclient;
        IPEndPoint End1 = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).Endpoint;
        Byte[] receiveBytes = Rx1.EndReceive(ar, ref End1);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved " + (i++) + "Frame and its data is -> " + receiveBytes + "\n");
        Rx.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback1), state1);
    }
}
class UdpState
{
  public  UdpClient Rxclient;
  public  IPEndPoint Endpoint;
}
```

Comment: new UdpClient(IPEndPoint localEP) is used to specify the **local** end point. *IPAddress.Any* lets the system choose which IPAddress to use.

Comment: ok instead of IPAddress.Any, I used IPAddress.Parse("10.169.20.15"), but still no success. Through wireshark, I am able to find that data has been transmitted to ip 10.169.20.15, but my application is not able to recieve it.

Comment: @Bas When you say, "I have two Ethernet ports in my system", do you mean two physical hosts connected together in an Ethernet network, or do you mean you a single host that has two Ethernet ports on it, i.e. two network interfaces that are connected together in an Ethernet network

Comment: @Joel Cunningham, I have a single host that has two ethernet ports

Answer (score 1):

If the two programs are running on the same host device and you want to communicate between them, you should use the [loopback interface](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) instead of sending out one physical interface and receiving on another.

The loopback interface is more efficient because it is all within software and is easier to use. Configure you sender to send to 127.0.0.1 and bind your receiver to 127.0.0.1. You can use the same ports in your example.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one reason you would actually want to use an external network to exchange data between two processes in the same machine, and that's if you want to detect whether the link between them (and intervening switches) is up.

For that you should use IEEE 802.1d Spanning Tree Protocol.  If and only if both ports converge to membership in the same tree, there's a link between them.